# Creating a SQL query according to dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, sql

How would I create a string which could act as a `where` clause?
At the moment, I am doing it this way:

```
string strquery = "select * from tbl_DR_data ";
string strq2 = "where [Year 1]='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'and Product='" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text +
                "'and Media='" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "'and Publication='" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text + "'and Genre='" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text +
                "'and Month='" + DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Value + "'and Section='" + DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
string str3 = strquery + strq2;
```

But the issue is that all drop down lists have to have a value within them. 
I want to be able to create a where statement according to what drop down has a value within init. So and example DDL1 and DDL4 have values but not include all the other dropdowns.

How would i go about doing this??

Comment: Be sure to use a parameterized query. Your code is ready for sql injection.

Comment: +1 @venerik. Also, use an ORM for Pete's sake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string strq2 = "where '";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 = strq2 + "[Year 1]='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + " and ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 = strq2 + "Product='" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text+ " and ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 = strq2 + "Media='" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text+ " and ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 = strq2 + "Publication='" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text+ " and ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 = strq2 + "Genre='" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text+ " and ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Value))
strq2 = strq2 + "Month='" + DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Value+ " and ";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Value))
strq2 = strq2 + "Section='" + DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Value+ " and ";
strq2 = strq2.Remove(strq2.Length - 5);
```

Comment: Works like a charm but only thing is that the first if always has to be executed

Answer (score 0):

you can probably format your select query as -

```
select * from tbl_DR_data 
where 
ISNULL( [YEAR 1], 'X') = ISNULL( DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, 'X') 
AND  ISNULL( Product, 'X') = ISNULL( DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text , 'X')
AND ... so on.
```

That way, if no values are chosen, that part of the wher clause will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You must learn and use the `SqlParameter` object..

```
string strq2 = "WHERE 1=1";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 += " AND [Year 1]=@Year1";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 += " AND [Product]=@Product";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 += " AND [Media]=@Media";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 += " AND [Publication]=@Publication";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text))
strq2 += " AND [Genre]=@Genre";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Value))
strq2 += " AND [Month]=@Month";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Value))
strq2 += " AND [Section]=@Section";
```